# TortoiseHg Folder Comparison Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: mercurial, diff, tortoisehg, codecompare

When I clicked [`Diff to Local`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWZV3.png) or [`Visual Diff`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNp3U.png), it used to be showing CodeCompare's Folder Comparison window, which is really nice looking. If you want to see how it looks like, please click on [this link](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/images/overview_screenshot_foldersynchronizationcopytoright.png). But whatever happened I don't know, it stoped working and now is showing me this disgusting window when I say "Diff to Local" and "Visual Diff":

[image]

I have checked all the possible solutions, and did everything I knew and found but nothing seems to be working. Here the mercurial.ini content, which also happens to be the global setting of TortoiseHG:

```
[ui]
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\Users\[Hidden]\ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
username = [Hidden]
merge = codecompare_merge

[tortoisehg]
fontdiff = Consolas,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
fontlist = Consolas,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
refreshwdstatus = always
fontcomment = Consolas,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
fontlog = Consolas,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
fontoutputlog = Consolas,8,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
editor = notepad++
vdiff = codecompare_diff

[auth]
default.prefix = https://bitbucket.org
default.username = [Hidden]
default.password = [Hidden]

[merge-tools]
codecompare_merge.regkey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CodeCompare_is1
codecompare_merge.regname=InstallLocation
codecompare_merge.regappend=CodeMerge.exe
codecompare_merge.args=/SC=TortoiseHg /TF=$other /MF=$local /RF=$output /BF=$base /TT="Other: $other" /MT="Local: $local" /RT="Output: $output" /BT="Base: $base"
codecompare_merge.binary=False
codecompare_merge.gui=True
codecompare_merge.checkconflicts=True
codecompare_merge.premerge=Keep

[extensions]
extdiff=

[extdiff]
cmd.codecompare=C:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\CodeCompare.exe
opts.codecompare=/SC=Hg /W /title1="$plabel1" /title2="$clabel" $parent $child

[merge-patterns]
*.*=codecompare_merge
```

When I first installed CodeCompare, I honestly didn't add any of these things. It worked nicely. However, when this problem started to occur recently, I found [this link](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/integration_mercurial.html) with the hope it may help me, and added everything in my Mercurial.ini file and no luck so far.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Note: `[Hidden]`s were containing sensitive data, like my computer name, username, and password.

Comment: Could you post your current mercurial.ini and MergeTools.rc (perhaps in a pastebin somewhere?).

Answer (score 1):

1. In (fresh) `MergeTools.rc` you already have 2 CodeCompare tools, extdiff not needed additionally (and your overloading in `[merge-tools]`)
2. You forgot one key in definition for diffing directory (can be uses in merge-tools section) `???.dirdiff=True`

MergeTools.rc define CodeCompare's both differ and merger in merge-tools, diff-definition

```
; 2-way diff only version of Code Compare
codecompare_diff.regkey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CodeCompare_is1
codecompare_diff.regname=InstallLocation
codecompare_diff.regappend=CodeCompare.exe
codecompare_diff.diffargs=/SC=TortoiseHg /title1="$plabel1" /title2="$clabel" $parent $child
codecompare_diff.diff3args=/SC=TortoiseHg /title1="$plabel1" /title2="$clabel" /title3="$plabel2" $parent1 $child $parent2
codecompare_diff.binary=False
codecompare_diff.gui=True
codecompare_diff.dirdiff=True
```

and your diff-tool in interface will be codecompare_diff

Comment: I did everything you mentioned above but they don't seem to be working. I think there is a bug with TortoiseHG.